# What are the difference between the different (Graphic Novel) editions of Watchmen?

Tags: dc, comics, watchmen

I am thinking of buying the Watchmen Graphic Novel in India but I'm confused about the different editions. They are

- [Watchmen (448 pages)](http://www.flipkart.com/watchmen-english/p/itme8n7jhwbjvzzs?pid=9781401245252&ref=L%3A2485194422826258282&srno=p_8&query=watchmen%20comics&otracker=from-search)
- [Watchmen (336 Pages)](http://www.flipkart.com/watchmen-english/p/itme8n7jhwbjvzzs?pid=9781401219260&ref=L%3A2485194422826258282&srno=p_16&query=watchmen+comics&otracker=from-search)
- [Watchmen: The Deluxe Edition](http://www.flipkart.com/watchmen-deluxe-english/p/itmdzvtffqqzpnfm?pid=9781401238964&ref=L%3A2485194422826258282&srno=p_5&query=watchmen+comics&otracker=from-search)
- [Watchmen: Absolute Edition](http://www.flipkart.com/watchmen-absolute-english/p/itmdyehejw5pkdrb?pid=9781401207137&ref=L%3A2485194422826258282&srno=p_4&query=watchmen+comics&otracker=from-search)
- [Watchmen: International Edition (448 pages)](http://www.flipkart.com/watchmen-international-english/p/itmdzhgqfnfzecwk?pid=9781401248192&ref=L%3A2485194422826258282&srno=p_3&query=watchmen+comics&otracker=from-search))
- [Watchmen (International Edition) 416 Pages](http://www.flipkart.com/watchmen-international-edition-english/p/itmdzhgqfnfzecwk?pid=9781401222666&ref=L%3A2485194422826258282&srno=p_1&query=watchmen+comics&otracker=from-search)

So what are main difference between different versions? Is there any additional materials in them or is this just a marketing ploy?

Comment: Very good question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Deluxe Edition](http://www.dccomics.com/graphic-novels/watchmen-deluxe-edition)

> Now, DC collects this series in the popular Deluxe Edition format.
>    - Includes sketches, bonus material and a new introduction by artist Dave Gibbons.
>    - Collects WATCHMEN #1-12.

[International Edition](http://www.dccomics.com/graphic-novels/watchmen-international-edition)

> Along with a new cover by Gibbons, this volume features the
>   high-quality, recolored pages from WATCHMEN: THE ABSOLUTE EDITION,
>   restored by WildStorm FX and original series colorist John Higgins.

[Absolute edition](http://www.dccomics.com/graphic-novels/watchmen-the-absolute-edition);

> Include[s] 48 pages of supplemental material produced exclusively for
>   the Graphitti Designs WATCHMEN hardcover edition and not seen since
>   their original publication. Included therein is a cornucopia of rare
>   and historically valuable treasures, including samples of Moore's
>   WATCHMEN scripts, the original WATCHMEN proposal, Gibbons's conceptual
>   art, cover roughs, and much, much more!

[Standard Softcover (TPB)](http://uk.ign.com/articles/2008/11/06/watchmen-buyers-guide)

> This collection has been in print more or less constantly since DC
>   first collected the series in the late '80s. It's cheap and it's
>   readily available, and that's all most readers need to hear. - [Contains the collected 1-12 issues]

[Standard Hardcover](http://uk.ign.com/articles/2008/11/06/watchmen-buyers-guide)

> In the same week that DC reprinted the Absolute Edition, they also
>   issued a new hardcover in the standard trim size. Presumably, DC hopes
>   to appeal to that segment of the audience that wants a sturdy
>   hardcover edition of Watchmen but doesn't want to fork over the dough
>   for the Absolute Edition. In terms of content, this hardcover falls
>   more in line with the paperback. It has the newer color job, and lacks
>   the copious extras of the Absolute Edition.

Answer (score 9):

The 448pg version - the first link provided - contains extra material written by other writers and editors plus some stuff from Dave Gibbons. This includes some character sketches early pencils and such. There is also an intro (I believe with dedications to his loved ones) written by Gibbons.

IF this is the edition I once owned with the same cover the intro is actually pretty cool. Gibbons gives some background on how the project came about and the umm lets call them special quirks Moore has when it comes to writing style. Also how the stress and demand the book required affected him during the project. An epic of a story where almost every page is 12 panels!? I am unaware of any work of the same caliber coming close to that kind of hand cramping gusto. I cannot remember if Alan Moore provided any extra introduction or epilogue in this ed.

The story and art are essentially the same in all editions it would seem. Most of them have the same page count of 448. The differences are really in bindings it seems. Link1 - paperback w/ intro & sketch, Link2 (436 pages actually) along with the last link are the only odd ducks. The rest vary in weight and prize due to the quality of covers. Thickness, extra book case, slips, etc.

More pages equals newer with more ppl gushing over the book no doubt. The comments do not mention any difference in printing, paper, or color application. So all are most likely the newer remastered coloring.

Comment: Watchmen famously uses a 9-panel grid, not 12 panels.

Comment: What he said.  I have the 446 page hardcover book.  The colors are improved, and there are notes about the creation of the story and the art.  The story itself is identical in each edition.